# Date updates to null

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to update certain values to a database using php that I have added earlier. One of the data I try to add is a date value. Although when adding the value for the first time, everything is added correctly. When I try to update the date value, the data changes to 0000-00-00 always. so I have the following questions :

1)what is the mistake I make and the date is not updated correctly?

2)How can I change the format of the date to be DD/MM/YYYY?

This is the update code (I know that I risk for SQL Injection but that is not my concern at this time) :

```
<?php 
 //DISPLAY A LIST OF ALL Files
$sql = "select * from news";
$result = mysqli_query($mydb, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mydb));

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){ 
?>

<table class="table table-striped" >
<thead>
<td><b>NewsID</b></td>
<td><b>Headline</b></td>
<td><b>Story</b></td>
<td><b>Date</b></td>
<td><b>Actions</b></td>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $NewsID = $rows['NewsID'];
    $Headline = $rows['Headline'];
    $Story = $rows['Story'];
    $Date= $rows['Date'];
 ?>
  <tr>
  <form method="post" id="action" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"> 
  <?php //if update button was pressed change all plain text to textfields to enable inline editing 
     if (isset($_POST['preUpdate']) && $_POST['NewsID']==$NewsID) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $NewsID ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Headline" value="<?php echo $Headline?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text"name="Story" value="<?php echo $Story?>"></td>
        <td><input type="date" name="Date" value="<?php echo $Date?>"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Save"/></td>
        <?php } 
else {  //These file will be displayed in plain text ?>
        <td><?php echo $NewsID; ?> </a></td>
        <td><?php echo $Headline; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Story; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $Date; ?></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="preUpdate" value="Update"/> 
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"/></td> 
        <?php } // end of if update button was pressed ?>
       <input type="hidden" name="NewsID" value="<?php echo $NewsID?>">

      </form>  
 </tr>
     <?php } //end of while loop that displays courses ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php }
```

Comment: What is the type of your date column ?

Comment: Please post the code that updates the table and sets the date.  All I see is a `select` and no `insert` or `update`.

Comment: one would think 1 of the 12 occurrences of the word update would show that

Comment: @AndrewCoder Coder there is an if which will either make the text show as text or as textfields if the update button is selected and will let you edit the data and update the values on the database

Comment: @Akshay The date column type is date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your datatype of date in table as `date`.

The standard format of `date` in mysql is `YYYY-MM-DD`, so you should store in same format. You are tryig to insert in different format, so date is getting stored as `0000-00-00`.You can change it to required format using `strtotime()`;

While storing

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

While displaying

```
echo date("required format",strtotime($date));
```

For formats, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

Comment: thanks for the answers, I now have correct values for my dates but for some reason I get the same date for each row of data so I will be searching for a solution to that

Comment: glad it helped you.:) If the answer was helpful, consider accepting and upvoting it.

Comment: same date while inserting or while fetching??

Comment: both when inserting a new value and updating the old values